# FileNotFoundExecption when trying to download PDF from URL with spaces

Tags: android, url

I'm trying to use the following code to download and then eventually view a PDF file.  The URL of the file is like this:

`http://www.example.com/directory/something.example.com This File.pdf`

I've tried replacing the spaces with %20, I've tried "UrlEncoder.encode", no matter what I get either FileNotFoundException or MalformedURLException (when encoding the URL).  Example exceptions:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
http://www.example.com/directory/something.example.com This File.pdf`

`java.io.FileNotFoundException:
http://www.example.com/directory/something.example.com%20This%20File.pdf`

`java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%directory%2Fsomething.example.com+This+File.pdf`

If I copy those paths into any browser it downloads fine.

```
        File file;
        try
        {
            String urlString = 
              "http://www.example.com/directory/something.example.com This File.pdf"
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            //URL url = new URL(URLEncoder.encode(urlString, "UTF-8"));
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "test.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            int bufferLength;
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            fileOutput.flush();
            fileOutput.close();
            inputStream.close();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Have you replaced spaces with `+`?

Comment: That doesn't even work when I try that in a browser.  Chrome, Firefox etc replace the spaces with %20 and that works.

Comment: The file name is "something.example.com This File.pdf"?

Comment: I'm guessing that you aren't actually missing the semicolon after the string in your actual code correct?

Comment: Also, there are errors in all three examples you posted. See my updated answer for what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException` will be returned if the server responds with a **404** error code. Sometimes the error code and the data returned do not match. You can check for this (and get whatever data was returned) using the following:

```
boolean isError = urlConnection.getResponseCode() >= 400;
InputStream inputStream =  = isError ? urlConnection.getErrorStream() : urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

And if you're connecting to a non-standard port, you can fix it by adding these headers to your request:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
```

Comment: The exception is thrown by `urlConnection.getInputStream()`

Answer (score 0):

Your UrlEncoder attempts have been wrong. Here's the javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
http://www.example.com/directory/something.example.com This File.pdf
Spaces were not encoded so it doesn't match your file.

java.io.FileNotFoundException:
http://www.example.com/directory/something.example.com%20This%20File.pdf
%20 are valid url symbols, so this also doesn't match your file.

java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%directory%2Fsomething.example.com+This+File.pdf
Slash after .com is not encoded properly. Results in an incorrectly encoded url.

1. With UrlEncoder, you should be encoding the file name and concatenating it with the URL, not encoding the entire url string and use UTF-8 encoding. Anything else (not UTF-8) is not guaranteed to work.
2. If manually encoding spaces don't then pass them through the UrlEncoder.

Comment: Passing just the filename through URLEncoder produces `http://www.example.com/directory/something.example.com+This+File.pdf` which the server does not recognize as the file, so I instead download an error page.  If I don't have control of the server, how can I resolve this?

Comment: That's strange. Before, you got a file not found exception when you passed in an incorrect file name. What changed?

Comment: I never passed in the '+' separated filename in my 3 examples except the wrongly encoded URL in case #3.